# Jquery Show/Hide Div

Tags: jquery, layout, html

I am trying to achieve like this.

I have total 4 div. each div have check box.

So it is like this

```
1  2  3  4
```

What I want to do is, when 2 , 3, 4 div checkbox are selectable. But Once div is checked, another 2 div will be hide.

Let's say, if i will choose 3, 2 and 4 will be hide. Till this stage, I am able to do. But the problem i got is about

After 2 and 4 is hide. Layout became like this

```
1    3
```

2 and 4 div are still there, so there's still spacing between them.

What I want to get is just

```
1 3
```

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: post some code of what you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand, you don't seem to be hiding the divs but the contents of the div. In order to make them completely invisible you need to use the `hide()` method.

```
$("#div2, #div4").hide();
```

this will take the divs out of the page flow completely

Answer (score 0):

what if you do something like this(to remove the innerHTML inside the divs):

$("div#1, div#3").html("");

Will this work???

Answer (score 0):

Put to checkboxes:

```
onclick="return swapdivs('div4');"
```

put this to divs

```
<div id="div4">
</div>
```

And this is your js:

```
function swapdivs(id){
    $("#"+id).toggle("fast");
    return false;
    };
```